# How to change a file's ownership in windows

Tags: c++, windows, ownership

I am trying to change a file's ownership through c++ in windows(windows 7 and up) to a specific user. I have read through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example but it does not seem to be of much help. I would like to be able to create a function like `SetFileOwner(LPTSTR user, LPTSTR fileStr)` that sets the owner of fileStr to be the specified user.

It seems that I need a SID to set the owner and then use `SetNamedSecurityInfo`. Is there another option that will allow me to set ownership by username? Is there a way to get SID from username(sorry if this question is stupid - I am not really into how windows rights and ownership work)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To translate username to SID, use [LookupAccountName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This seems to be just what I was looking for. I will try to prototype later and will accept your answer if this works